# How do i create an item list where the item has a mixture of links and text

Tags: 8

If I add the following to my controller, the first item in the list displays correctly, but once I concatinate in text, the links are all escaped.

```
 $basic_items[] = \Drupal::l('Basic example',Url::fromRoute('flot_examples.basic_usage'));
$basic_items[] = \Drupal::l('Different graph types', Url::fromRoute('flot_examples.series_types')) .
" and " .
\Drupal::l('simple categories/textual data', Url::fromRoute('flot_examples.categories'));

$output['basic'] = [
  '#title' => 'Basic Usage',
  '#theme' => 'item_list',
  '#items' => $basic_items,
];
```

I know the `l()` function in deprecated, and I should be using:

```
$basic_items[] = ['#type' => 'link', '#title' => 'Basic Example', '#url' => Url::fromRoute('flot_examples.basic_usage')];
```

instead, but I can't figure out how to get that to work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler method is to use the t() function:

```
$basic_items[] = \Drupal::l('Basic example', Url::fromRoute('flot_examples.basic_usage'));
$string = '<a href=":options_page">Setting various options</a> and <a href=":annotating_page">annotating a chart</a>';
$options = [
  ':options_page' => Url::fromRoute('flot_examples.basic_options')->toString(),
  ':annotating_page' => Url::fromRoute('flot_examples.annotating')->toString(),
];
$basic_items[] = t($string, $options);

$output['basic'] = [
  '#title' => 'Basic Usage',
  '#theme' => 'item_list',
  '#items' => $basic_items
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple render arrays in each item.

```
$basic_items[] = \Drupal::l('Basic example', Url::fromRoute('flot_examples.basic_usage'));

$basic_items[] = [
  'graph' => \Drupal::l('Different graph types', Url::fromRoute('flot_examples.series_types')),
  'separate' => " and ",
  'data' => \Drupal::l('simple categories/textual data', Url::fromRoute('flot_examples.categories'))
];

$output['basic'] = [
  '#title' => 'Basic Usage',
  '#theme' => 'item_list',
  '#items' => $basic_items
];
```

P.S.
You can use the \Drupal\Core\Link class to create links instead of the l function.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. I'll keep playing around with it though.

Comment: The documentation suggested it will work, I'll play around with it in my free time and update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Where in the documentation do you see this?

Comment: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_item_list/8.2.x

Comment: It reads to me that $items is an array of a combination of strings, or render arrays. Each element in the array will be a new item in the list. How do I construct a generic render array which combines text and links?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a better way, but what I did was to change the twig template for the default item_list to include the case where the item is an array.

```
<li{{ item.attributes }}>{% if item.value is iterable %}{% for snip in item.value %}{{ snip }}{% endfor %}{% else %}{{ item.value }}{% endif %}</li>
```